# Set default select list value Angular2

Tags: html, select, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I want to set the default option for the select in angular 2 as "Select an option". Here is the code that I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CustomFix">Select an option:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <select id="example" name="example" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="exampleArray" (ngModelChange)="changes()">
                                <option disabled selected>Select a Custom Fix</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let example of exampleArray" [ngValue]="example">{{example.attribute }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
changes(){
console.log(this.example.option);
}
```

I have the line in my html:

```
<option disabled selected>Select a Custom Fix</option>
```

How can I enable this as the default option? It is separate from my array used with ngModel

Comment: How can an option be both disabled and selected? If it's disabled, then by definition it can't be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `[ngValue]` then you need to assign the **identical** object instance to `exampleArray`. Another object instance with the same properties and values won't do.

If you use `[value]="..."` instead of `[ngValue]`, then only strings can be used and for string comparison to different string instances containing the same characters are considered equal, but that's not the case for object instances where `exampleArray` needs to reference the exact same object reference used with `[ngValue]`.

Actually

```
[(ngModel)]="exampleArray"
```

in your example is invalid, because the model should not be the array that is used to generate the `<option>` elements, it should be a property that holds the selected value.

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CustomFix">Select an option:</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="example" name="example" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="changes()">
                <option disabled selected>Select a Custom Fix</option>
                <option *ngFor="let example of exampleArray" [ngValue]="example">{{example.attribute }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
constructor() {
  this.selectedItem = exampleArray[1]; // will make the 2nd element of `exampleArray` the selected item
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have this option selected at the start - that's usually when the `ngModel`'s value is `undefined`, you just have to tell Angular that this option is responsible for `undefined` value, so it should be:

```
<option disabled [ngValue]="undefined">Select a Custom Fix</option>
```

You also need do correct your `[(ngModel)]` binding - right now you're trying to bind selected value to.. the array itself. You should rather bind to some other property, e.g.:

```
<select id="example" name="example" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="example">
```

(You can see the working solution here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zu29ztqaaDym1GYDAhtJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You should give that option a value, bind the select element to an ID variable, and set that variable on component load.

```js
// controller
exampleArraySelectedValue = -1;
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="CustomFix">Select an option:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="example" name="example" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="exampleArraySelectedValue" (ngModelChange)="changes()">
      <option value="-1">Select a Custom Fix</option>
      <option *ngFor="let example of exampleArray" [ngValue]="example">{{example.attribute }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```