# How to add undefined value in angular select option

Tags: angular, select

I am trying to add a disable value in my Angular `select` `option`. For example I have a dropdown where I have value a value 2 as an option I want to just show that value and it should not be accepted.

I am doing this in my angular HTML code:

```
<select id="anything" class="selectpicker" class='select-option' required [(ngModel)]='data.years' name="years" (ngModelChange)="toYear(data.years)">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected> Year </option>
  <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of years' [ngValue]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

This is my code here as you can see I am using this code:

```
<option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected>Year</option>
```

This is visible but not selectable, I am loading values in loop 
I am using this data to loop:

```
years = [
  "All",
  "2005-06",
  "2006-07",
  "2007-08",
  "2008-09",
  "2009-10",
  "2010-11",
  "2011-12",
  "2012-13",
  "2013-14",
  "2014-15",
  "CAGR",
];
```

I want to disable `CAGR` in this dropdown as it is undefined and disabled in Year

Comment: instead of using `[ngValue]` try using `value` only

Comment: Do you have answer to my question.

Comment: You mean that user should not select option 1? It must be disabled.

Comment: In option one whatever I am showing I need to disbale when I am loading year in loop. I need to put condition if value = cagr then [ngValue]="undefined" disabled this is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640085/set-default-select-list-value-angular2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `[disabled]="option === 'CAGR'"` in `option` that you're looping through:

```
<select 
  id = "anything" 
  class="selectpicker" 
  class='select-option' 
  required 
  [(ngModel)]='data.years' 
  name="years" 
  (ngModelChange)="toYear(data.years)">
    <option 
      [ngValue]="undefined" 
      disabled  
      selected>
      Year
    </option>
    <option 
      class='option' 
      *ngFor='let option of years'
      [disabled]="option === 'CAGR'"
      [ngValue]="option">
      {{option}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-list-dropdown-drop-down-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Can we use condition for example in loop if value is cagr then do this else use that value. This solved my problem

Comment: Glad I could help :)